# working with forms in HTML 5

Tags: html, forms, webserver

i have tried the following code while trying to learn html forms:

```
<head>

    <title>Example</title>

</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" action="http://titan:8080/form">
        <input name="fave"/>
        <input name="name"/>
        <button>Submit Vote</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

but its not working the webpage shows this message: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find titan:8080"

Answer (score 1):

The `action` attribute must contain a valid URL. In this case, the server part of the URL is not valid, since `titan` is not a valid domain name. It should be something like `titan.example` or `titan.foobar.example.com` (naturally, you need to use the *real*, working domain name; the names I used are guaranteed to not work, i.e. for use as dummy examples only).

Alternatively, if you are running a local HTTP server, at port 8080, in the computer where you use the HTML page, use the reserved name `localhost` as in `action="http://localhost:8080/form">`.

Answer (score 0):

The url you have provided `http://titan:8080/form` is timing out ensure you have the correct url or that the page is live.

Comment: with which URL should i replace it ?

Comment: with the url that you are trying to send the data to.

Comment: yea i got the idea, but am taking a training so do suggest any url to complete the examples am trying to learn correctly, it supposes to send data via text boxes then receive it in a table

Comment: you want to echo your results onto the page that the user is submitting the results from? or are you trying to send the data elsewhere like an email address or database?

Comment: how i can do both ways please?
i reach this level in the book and i stuck, i cant complete the book examples ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>Example</title>
```

```
<form method="post" action="#a">
    <input name="fave"/>
    <input name="name"/>
    <button>Submit Vote</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <form method="post" action="--Your FileName---">